# detangle preserve noweb

Tags: org-mode, org-babel, literate-programming, tangle, noweb

I've recently gotten into literate Programming with org-mode.

I'd like to be able to write all my functions across multiple Code Blocks, tangle them into a files but also test them from inside the org buffer.

So I have to use noweb to include all dependent Code Blocks for them to be executable.
When refining the Code I find it more pleasant to do this in the tangled files, because I can use the major-modes and then just detangle everything back into the Code Blocks.

## Example

Function `Foo`

```
#+name: foo
#+begin_src C :tangle file.c
    int foo(){
        return 1;
    }
#+end_src
```

Main function depends on `foo`

```
#+begin_src C :noweb :tangle file.c
#include <stdio.h>

//include foo
<<foo>>

int main(void)
{
    // call foo
    printf("%d\n", foo());
    return 0;
}
#+end_src
```

But when I detangle the files it expands the noweb and when I use `:noweb strip-tangle` it will remove the noweb includes from my Code Blocks and make them not executable whenever i detangle the sources.

Is there a Solution for this?
Maybe to have a codeblock prefix, which is not affected by detangle?
Or to specify the dependent Code Block in the header args somehow?

Or is there a way to link Source Blocks without noweb?

I find this approach really interesting and would love to be able to use it properly.